# Merge Modules for Crystal Reports 2008 - Needs a Keycode?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, merge

I've not been able to find any information on this, but is a keycode required to be embedded in the CR2008 merge modules for a .NET distribution?  They used to require this (which had to be done using ORCA), but I've not found any information on this for CR2008.

Answer (score 1):

I would email Crystal Reports (Business Objects).  They have helped me in the past with KeyCode issues.